# Cannot login after installing nvidia drivers. Gtx 1080. Limited 1024x768

Tags: drivers, nvidia, login, display, display-resolution

Im new on ubuntu, when I installed the drivers, it got stuck at the end of "Applying changes", at a point I rebooted and when I tried to login, it looped, I putted my password, it seems it worked, but then it goes back to the login page. I am able to use CLI and login through CLI, I also tried to install the drivers through CLI but at the end an error came up, and when I rebooted the same happend, Im trying to install drivers because Im stuck at 1024x768 resolution, I cannot change that. How can I change the resolution/ install the drivers without loop? 
Thanks.